# Captcha creation without a third party

Tags: java, php

Newbie over here. I'm designing and coding a few websites using Adobe Dreamweaver. I'm about 3 months in to web development at my current job at this point. I haven't had any formal training in web development, but I have an eye for design and attention to detail.

However, more technical things are difficult for me as I'm just getting started. I want to create a self contained Captcha within two websites **without using a third party service or any downloadable plugins.** This is important, because I am creating the website for the company I work for full time as part of my job description.

How would I go about making a simple contact form and captcha using PHP & Java for example? I'm only slightly familiar with PHP and Java.

If someone could just explain this to me in an idiot-proof way I'd really appreciate it. I've been browsing Stack Overflow, but I can't seem to find anything specific and I'd prefer a fresh answer.

Thanks all. I'm also not familiar with most of the jargon yet, so forgive me for my lack of knowledge presently.

If this is an incredibly stupid question also, I apologize - but I still really need an answer.

Comment: I think you mean PHP & Javascript.

Comment: No need for JavaScript, anyways.

Comment: As far as the CAPTCHA goes you should check the [official webpage](http://www.captcha.net/).  Although, note the 5th bullet point under the Guidelines section; you may want to rethink building your own.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP:
start a session
create a random string
store the string into a session variable
create an image to display using php imagecreate
use imagettftext to position the characters one at a time at random angle
Verify user input against the stored session variable

Comment: Ideally you should have this code in a php file and reference it into the image tag where you want to show the captcha image